# un-expected bug in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my `App`, I was trying to save marks of student in `SQLite Table`, and show those in `ListView`, My `App` also have functionality of `SORT` orders, when I enter the marks of students 89, 78, 90, 100 respectivily and after this I want to sort the  `List` in marks ascending order the name of student with 100 marks is at the top of the list and then the students having marks 78, 89, 90, apear in list one after other, why is this bug occuring?
My DB schema is :

```
public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
public static final String COL_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String COL_MARKS = "marks";


protected static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + FRIEND_TABLE +
        " (" + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "   +
        COL_NAME + " TEXT, " + COL_ADDRESS + " TEXT," +
        COL_MARKS + " TEXT)";
```

the sorting logic is in a `PrefrenceActivity` that looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Choose a sort order"
        android:key="sort_order"
        android:summary="Choose your preferred sort order"
        android:title="Sort Order" 
        android:entries="@array/sort_names"
        android:entryValues="@array/sort_clauses"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

the arrays are :

```
<string-array name="sort_names">
    <item>By Name, Ascending</item>
    <item>By Name, Descending</item>
    <item>By Roll</item>
    <item>By Address, Ascending</item>
    <item>By Address, Descending</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="sort_clauses">
    <item>name ASC</item>
    <item>name DESC</item>
    <item>marks ASC</item>
    <item>address ASC</item>
    <item>address DESC</item>
</string-array>
```

can any one find the solution of this mentioned bug please!

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get error messages, or does it just not work as expected? You also haven't shown us the code that actually accesses the database, or your list adapter...

Comment: dear `marks ASC` sort oder does not work correctly, because student having marks 100 comes at the top of list, that shoul come in last in above case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a bug in SQLite or Android, this is a bug in your database schema. You've defined your `marks` column as `TEXT` and the string `"100"` sorts before the string `"89"` (in ascending order) even though the number `100` sorts after the number `89`; the sorting looks backwards in descending order for the same reason. Your `marks` column should probably be an `integer`, then your sorting will work the way you expect it to.

Comment: Just to be clear- while the reasoning in the answer is perfectly accurate, the string "89" sorts before the string "100" in **`marks DESC`** and NOT **`marks ASC`** as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @TheCodeArtist: Right, I should have been more explicit. Better now?

Comment: Yup. Now the explanation seems easier to follow. +1.